# readonly property for a foundation object in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, foundation

How do you refactor `@property (readonly) NSDate *creationDate;` into a Swift property of a struct?

```
struct structObject {

    var name: String
    var completed: Bool
    var creationDate: NSDate

}
```

Should the property be configured as a `get` property exclusively? In Objective-C the code is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ToDoItem : NSObject

@property NSString *itemName;
@property BOOL completed;
@property (readonly) NSDate *creationDate;

@end
```

Comment: `struct Object {
    let name: String
    var completed: Bool
    let creation: Date
    init(name: String, completed: Bool = false) {
        self.name = name
        self.completed = completed
        self.creation = Date()
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to do it.

If you want it to be set at creation time and not changed afterwards, use `let` instead of `var`.

If you want it to only be changed by the object's own methods, use `private(set)`.